# Promotion Management Tool from Command Line

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to do code migration from one environment to other(Say DEV to STG) without using PMT Tool.

I have the code for doing the promotion in command Line. But the thing is I am trying to promote in the server itself without taking any backup. So i am in need of two things.

1)Path of the report in the server. In PMT we are able to see ther report under particular folder so it has a proper path. Similarly how can i find the path of a report at server level

2)Could the code only be used if there is a BIAR file?

The code which i am talking about:

```
action=promote
importLocation=Path // tHE DOUBT PART
CMS="CMS name:port number"
Destination_CMS="CMS name:port number"
Destination_userName="username"
Destination_password="password"
Destination_authentication="secEnterprise"
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [admin guide](http://help-legacy.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo42/en/sbo42sp3_bip_admin_en.pdf).

The command-line BIAR utility does not support direct system-to-system migrations.  You can only export to BIAR or import from BIAR.

The `importLocation`parameter specifies the location of the BIAR file to import.  It has nothing to do with the location of objects in the CMS.

You don't specify reports to migrate using their path, but rather with a CMS query.  See the `exportQuery` parameter.

You can also use the command line tool to perform a migration using a saved PM job.  So, you would still use PM to create an export job (and select the objects to include), but then use the command line tool to perform the migration

Comment: So without using the PM Tool code migration cannot be done unless the reports(or any other objects) are stored offline?

Comment: Your only other option for direct CMS-to-CMS migrations would be to write a program using the Java SDK.

Comment: How can I use the Java SDK? I am not aware of it. Could you please guide me through it. Even if i use it will i be able find the reports' path at server level?